# Gmail & Google Mail Are Linked to the same account for Virgin Media customers causing Ask Ubuntu to create two accounts

Tags: discussion, status-completed, email

Virgin Media use Google Mail as their email client and because of this my `toby[dot]whaymand [at] googlemail [dot] com` account defaults to my`tobywhaymand [at] gmail [dot] com` account which has caused Ask Ubuntu to create two separate accounts under my name.

I do have an outstanding question under my 'gmail' account and I am no longer able to log into that account has the owner which is causing problems because I really need to get my wireless router working.

Answer (score 2):

No worries, I'll merge the accounts.

Edit: And it's done.